# Why is ComponentShouldUpdate preventing Comments from Rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle

I implemented the componentShouldUpdate in the code below to try and speed up performance. This goal was accomplished, but now the comments don't render. Browser console shows that everything is being received, though. There's also a div that renders the number of comments and that is being updated as well.

```
            class ProposalDetail extends React.Component {
                      constructor(props) {
                        super(props);
                        this.state = {
                          sortedComments: []
                        };
                      }
                      componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
                        if((!prevProps.proposal || Object.keys(prevProps.proposal).length === 0 ) &&
                          this.props.proposal && Object.keys(this.props.proposal).length > 0 &&
                          this.props.proposal.status === 4 ){
                          prevProps.onFetchProposalVoteStatus(prevProps.token);
                        }
                        this.handleUpdateOfComments(prevProps, this.props);
                      }
                      shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
                        console.log('thisProps', this.props.comments)
                        console.log('nextProps', nextProps.comments)
                        if (this.props.comments === nextProps.comments) {
                            return true
                        }
                        else {
                            return false
                        }
                      }
                      componentDidMount() {
                        this.props.onFetchLikedComments(this.props.token);
                      }
                      componentWillUnmount() {
                        this.props.resetLastSubmittedProposal();
                      }
                      handleUpdateOfComments = (currentProps, nextProps) => {
                        let sortedComments;

                        if(!nextProps.comments || nextProps.comments.length === 0) {
                          return;
                        }
                        // sort option changed
                        if(currentProps.commentsSortOption !== nextProps.commentsSortOption) {
                          sortedComments = updateSortedComments(
                            this.state.sortedComments,
                            nextProps.commentsSortOption
                          );
                        }

                        // new comment added
                        if(currentProps.comments.length !== nextProps.comments.length) {
                          const isEmpty = currentProps.comments.length === 0;
                          const newComments = isEmpty ?
                            nextProps.comments :
                            [nextProps.comments[nextProps.comments.length - 1]]
                              .concat(this.state.sortedComments);
                          sortedComments = updateSortedComments(
                            newComments,
                            currentProps.commentsSortOption,
                            nextProps.commentsvotes,
                            isEmpty
                          );
                        }

                        // usernames aren't fully merged into comments
                        const commentWithoutAnUsername = comments => comments.filter(c => !c.username)[0];
                        if (commentWithoutAnUsername(this.state.sortedComments) && !commentWithoutAnUsername(nextProps.comments)) {
                          sortedComments = updateSortedComments(
                            nextProps.comments,
                            currentProps.commentsSortOption,
                            nextProps.commentsvotes,
                            false
                          );
                        }

                        // commentsvotes changed
                        if(nextProps.commentsvotes && !isEqual(currentProps.commentsvotes, nextProps.commentsvotes)) {
                          const updatedComments = getUpdatedComments(nextProps.commentsvotes, nextProps.comments);
                          const newComments = mergeNewComments(this.state.sortedComments, updatedComments);
                          sortedComments = updateSortedComments(
                            newComments,
                            currentProps.commentsSortOption,
                            nextProps.commentsvotes,
                            false
                          );
                        }

                        // comment gets censored
                        if(nextProps.censoredComment && !isEqual(currentProps.censoredComment, nextProps.censoredComment)) {
                          sortedComments = updateSortedComments(
                            nextProps.comments,
                            currentProps.commentsSortOption,
                            nextProps.commentsvotes,
                            true
                          );
                        }

                        if(sortedComments) {
                          this.setState({ sortedComments });
                          console.log('setState', this.state.sortedComments);

                        }
                      }
                      render() {
                        const {
                          isLoading,
                          proposal,
                          token,
                          error,
                          markdownFile,
                          otherFiles,
                          onFetchData,
                          ...props
                        } = this.props;
                        console.log(this.props);
                        const comments = this.state.sortedComments;
                        return (
                          <div className="content" role="main">
                            <div className="page proposal-page">
                              {error ? (
                                <Message
                                  type="error"
                                  header="Proposal not found"
                                  body={error} />
                              ) : (
                                <Content  {...{
                                  isLoading,
                                  error,
                                  bodyClassName: "single-page comments-page",
                                  onFetchData: () => onFetchData(token),
                                  listings: isLoading ? [] : [
                                    {
                                      allChildren: [{
                                        kind: "t3",
                                        data: {
                                          ...proposalToT3(proposal, 0).data,
                                          otherFiles,
                                          selftext: markdownFile ? getTextFromIndexMd(markdownFile) : null,
                                          selftext_html: markdownFile ? getTextFromIndexMd(markdownFile) : null
                                        }
                                      }]
                                    },
                                    { allChildren: commentsToT1(comments) }
                                  ],
                                  ...props
                                }} />
                              )}
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        );
                      }
                    }

                    export default ProposalDetail;
```

Comment: You are checking for equality between two different objects. Though the contents of nextProps.comments and this.props.comments may be the same, they point to a different object. Find a way to check their contents.

Comment: it may be helpful to put your code into a sandbox like https://stackblitz.com

Comment: Hmmm okay I never thought about the accessing the contents. I just tried adding .length (since comments is an array) but still no avail. Any other ideas why adding componentShouldUpdate would make the comments not render?

Comment: Could you add the structure of a comment?

Answer (score 6):

It’s not componentShouldUpdate but shouldComponentUpdate

shouldComponentUpdate basically decide whether the component requires re rendering or not. This method either returns true or false only. By default this method returns true which means the component needs re rendering always whenever setState happens or props received irrespective of the state and props comparison.

So in your case you are comparing comments incorrectly in shouldComponentUpdate. You need to return true only when current props and previous props are not equal otherwise false but you are checking vice versa.

The below code would work

```
     shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
                    console.log('thisProps', this.props.comments)
                    console.log('nextProps', nextProps.comments)
                    if (JSON.stringify(this.props.comments) !== JSON.stringify(nextProps.comments)) {
                        return true
                    }
                    else {
                        return false
                    }
                  }
```

Comment: This code won't work since `comments` is an array/object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
JSON.stringify(this.props.comments) === JSON.stringify(nextProps.comments)
```

This **dirty hack** *could* help.

The problem is that you cannot compare two arrays in such a way you do.

Comment: Hmm why is that?

Comment: Items have to be in the exact same order, in order for this to work.
Try JSON.stringify([1,2]) === JSON.stringify([2,1]) // false

Comment: That is why I wrote: COULD (not definitely) help. And I called this a DIRTY HACK.